# MySQL inexplicable permissions issue

Tags: mysql

I have a servlet set up to make a connection with MySql. I have two databases (testDb and jumpGate) and two corresponding users (testUser@localhost and jumpGate@localhost). When I run my tests with the testUser and testDb, it works fine, but when I run with the live user and database, I get "Access denied for user 'jumpGate'@'localhost' (using password: YES)". I cannot find any meaningful difference between the test and live versions. I have tested that the password is correct and given the appropriate grants.

These are the properties files that the Servlet uses to make a connection:

```
#Test database properties 
dbName=testDb 
dbUser=testUser 
dbPassword=password 

#Live database properties 
dbName=jumpGate 
dbUser=jumpGate 
dbPassword=**********
```

I can effectively rule out any issue with the Java code, as merely swapping one file for the other is the difference between success and failure.

Here is my verification that the databases exist and that the users have the right grants to their respective databases.

```
mysql> show databases; 
+--------------------+ 
| Database | 
+--------------------+ 
| information_schema | 
| admin | 
| cdcol | 
| jumpgate | 
| mysql | 
| performance_schema | 
| phpmyadmin | 
| testdb | 
| webauth | 
+--------------------+ 
9 rows in set (0.00 sec) 

mysql> show grants for 'testUser'@'localhost'; 
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| Grants for testUser@localhost | 
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'testUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*****************************************' | 
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testdb`.* TO 'testUser'@'localhost' | 
| GRANT INSERT ON `admin`.`connections` TO 'testUser'@'localhost' | 
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
3 rows in set (0.00 sec) 

mysql> show grants for 'jumpGate'@'localhost'; 
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| Grants for jumpGate@localhost | 
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'jumpGate'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*****************************************' | 
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `jumpgate`.* TO 'jumpGate'@'localhost' | 
| GRANT INSERT ON `admin`.`connections` TO 'jumpGate'@'localhost' | 
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If anyone can offer insight into why the live version is behaving differently, it would be appreciated.

Note: this question was originally posted [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,621058,621058#msg-621058), but, as of now, I haven't received a response.

Comment: `flush privileges`? Also, can you connect with `mysql -u 'jumpGate'@'localhost' -pPassword jumpgate`?

Comment: Sebas, thank you for your input. I have tried flush privileges and it had no effect. I am indeed able to log in from the console with 'mysql -u 'jumpGate' -p' etc. (the @'localhost' is implied). I even copy/pasted the password from the properties file.

Comment: the @localhost is not always implied. Please run `mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;` as root

Comment: agreed. In this case, I've verified that it is. The results of the query you asked for: 
jumpGate | %, 
root | %, 
testUser | %, 
root | 127.0.0.1, 
root | ::1, 
[empty] | localhost, 
jumpGate | localhost, 
pma | localhost, 
root | localhost, 
testUser | localhost

Comment: delete all users `'jumpGate'@'%'`, `'root'@'%'` and `'testUser'@'%'`. Then specify all the time the localhost in your connection parameters. Check that you affected the grants to the right users (it seems so, but just in case...)

Comment: thanks for the tip. I'll try that when I can. An update broke my development environment, so I have some work to do before this becomes testable again.